# Azure: how to deploy a subdir from a Visual Studio project?

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2015, azure-web-app-service, msdeploy, webdeploy

I have been struggling with this for a while now, and I feel I must be missing something obvious...

We are writing a web application using Visual Studio 2015, Typescript, angular, bower, grunt etc.. The project builds all the HTML, SASS and Typescript files into a directory `www` that is ready for deployment to a web server.

The resulting project structure looks like this (generated/copied files in parentheses):

```
OurProject/
   bower_components/
   node_modules/
   typings/
   source/
      index.html
      ...lots of .ts, .sass and .html files
   www/
      js/
         (...javascript libraries...)
      (index.html)
      (app.min.js)
      (app.min.css)
```

When we deploy this project to our Azure web site, I would *like* to see the following structure:

```
OurProject.azurewebsites.net/
   js/
      ...various libraries...
   index.html
   app.min.js
   app.min.css
```

But what we *actually* get is this - i.e. the whole project tree, including sources, build tools etc.:

```
OurProject.azurewebsites.net/
   bower_components/
   node_modules/
   typings/
   source/
      index.html
      ...lots of .ts, .sass and .html files
   www/
      (index.html)
      (app.min.js)
      (app.min.css)
```

This has the disadvantages of

- publishing our source code
- spamming Azure (node_modules is *huge*)
- having the landing page whiz.bang.com/www (instead of just whiz.bang.com)

There MUST be a way to tell the Visual Studio 2015 publishing engine "only publish the www subdir" - but can anyone tell me how?

### Attempted so far:

I've tried following the recipe on [Sayed Hashimis blog](http://sedodream.com/2010/05/01/WebDeploymentToolMSDeployBuildPackageIncludingExtraFilesOrExcludingSpecificFiles.aspx), describing how to include and exclude selected files and directories from deployment.

Apart from requiring hand-editing of undocumented pubxml features, this still doesn't fix the "awkward landing page" issue.

AND whenever you add a new directory to the project, you have to update the exclude-list.

### Another attempt:

One solution is to add a web site project ("Add existing web site...") referencing the OurProject/www/ directory:

```
OurSolution/
   OurProject/
      bower_components/
      node_modules/
      typings/
      source/
         index.html
         ...lots of .ts, .sass and .html files
      www/
         js/
            ...various libraries...
         (index.html)
         (app.min.js)
         (app.min.css)
   WebSiteProject (references existing web site ..\OurProject\www)/
      js/
         ...various libraries...
      index.html
      app.min.js
      app.min.css
```

This project (WebSiteProject) can then be deployed to Azure, yielding the desired result.

But this seems a very roundabout way to achieve something simple...

Answer (score 0):

According to your requirement, I did some testing on my side.
I could deploy the contents within subdir to the root directory of Azure Web App, please follow the steps below:

1. Create a MVC website with the same project structure as you mentioned
   [image]
2. Edit your publish profile, add some MSBuild Task before you deploy to Azure. You could define a Target with RemoveDir, Move tasks which execute after CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForMsdeploy and put it after PropertyGroup in your publish profile.
   The following is the detailed code, you could copy and paste to your publish profile.

```html
<Target Name="DeploySubFolder" AfterTargets="CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForMsdeploy">
  <!--1.Deleting Folders except www-->
  <ItemGroup>
    <_FolderToDelete Include="$(_PackageTempDir)\bower_components" />
    <_FolderToDelete Include="$(_PackageTempDir)\node_modules" />
    <_FolderToDelete Include="$(_PackageTempDir)\source" />
    <_FolderToDelete Include="$(_PackageTempDir)\typings" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <RemoveDir Directories="@(_FolderToDelete)" />

  <!--2.Copying files,folders from www to root directory-->
  <ItemGroup>
    <_FileToMove Include="$(_PackageTempDir)\www\**" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Move SourceFiles="%(_FileToMove.Identity)" DestinationFolder="$(_PackageTempDir)\%(RecursiveDir)" />

  <!--3.Deleting the empty folder www-->
  <RemoveDir Directories="$(_PackageTempDir)\www" />
</Target>
```

3. Deploy web application to Azure with the modified publish profile.
4. Check the structure of your web application in Azure Web App via KUDU

[image]